# How to paste a text from textbox to some other application without using SIP?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have made my own keypad.I know about the copy paste feature of WP7. I want to paste the copied text from textbox to some other application without using SIP.

Issues:

1. Copy the text by using default copy paste feature of WP7.
2. Get the copied text means from where i can get the copied text.
3. Now i don't want to use SIP to paste the text because i m hiding the SIP and using my own custom keypad.
4. I want to paste the copied text to some other application. So how to do this. Is it can be done with clipboard or through some other way.
   Need some links to do so.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of the framework there is no API for working with the clipboard, though the Silverlight 4 Clipboard API will be coming in the next version.

However, if Matt Lacey has produced a solution that works by saving text information in JPEG images. You would be able to access this virtual clipboard from any of your own applications. http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2011/03/wp7clipboard-clipboard-api-for-wp7dev.html

Answer (score 0):

While not possible now, one of the slides from Mix included a reference to a "Clipboard API" as part of the extras we'll get in the move to Silverlight 4 which is coming with Mango.
Hopefully that will complete the picture with regard to copy & paste / clipboard functionality.

Comment: Indeed. It will be a set-only API for developers. They will be able to use `SetText` to set clipboard content but won't be able to trigger the pasting process unless the user does it himself.