# A way to copy to click board for wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using Clipboard in WP7 programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160352/using-clipboard-in-wp7-programming)

For example you have a long text in a textblock and you want to have a button to automatically copy and paste the large text onto your clipboard so you can paste it in word mobile or some other app. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is no copy-paste API in windows phone 7 now.](http://twitter.com/#!/ckindel/status/23141333992472576) Maybe it'll appear in Mango.

Comment: Thanks, guess I'll have to wait

Answer (score 0):

The Windows phone team have recently blogged about their work adding clipboard functionality to the next release of the OS. So you'll have to wait until then.

Answer (score 0):

Please see:
[using Clipboard in WP7 programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160352/using-clipboard-in-wp7-programming)
and
[How to paste a text from textbox to some other application without using SIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959872/how-to-paste-a-text-from-textbox-to-some-other-application-without-using-sip)